# How to create array of templates - c++

Tags: c++

I have created a Priority Queue class with templates.
named it PQ. 
How can I create an array of PQ's in which each element would be PQ from different type?

tried to do something like this but it didn't work:

```
    template <class T>
PQ<T> *arr[10]; //void pointer can point to everything
arr[0] = new PQ<string>;
arr[1] = new PQ<int>;
```

edit1:

I added
code

```
 template <class T>
class PQ : public Pointer_Base
```

and

```
  class Pointer_Base
{
public:
    virtual ~Pointer_Base();//virtual DTOR
   virtual void showall();
};
```

and then in main I wrote:

```
Pointer_Base * arr[2];
PQ<string> first;
PQ<int> second;
arr[0] = first;
```

and it says error on the line arr[0]=first :

> "no suitable conversion from PQ to Pointer_base* exsit"

why I get this error if I implemented the virtual functions?
P.S:
 showall function just runs over the queue and print all the values in it and their priority.I know I might have done it with cout and operator overloading but It was easier and faster for me to do it this way for now.

Comment: As I have not got a clue as to PQ definition I cannot help you

Comment: For this you would need some kind of pointer-to-base implementation and have your `PQ` class inherit from a base class, then make your array (or vector) be of type `Base*`. Or you can opt for something like `boost::any`

Comment: Put more generally, these templates create distinct and unique types.  So your question is more generalized: "How do I create an array that can hold different types?"  This has been asked and answered several times on stackoverflow.

Comment: ...or a `void *`, if you dare.

Comment: Namely, don't do this.  Keep your types separate as much as possible.  Anything else is just asking for bugs.

Comment: @black I actually tried to work with void*, didn't went very well.
TBohne why not using void * if possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a perfect candidate for having your `PQ` class inherit from a base class, and store a `std::vector` or `std::array` of type `Base*`. Your `PQ` class would then need to implement some virtual functions defined in `Base`.  Something like this may suit your needs:

```
class base
{
  public:

    // virtual functions that every PQ must implement

     virtual ~base() {}

};

template<class T>
class PQ : public base
{
   // implement the virtual functions
};
```

Then to use this, you would use something like:

```
std::vector<base*> priority_queues; // or even std::unique_ptr<base>
```

However, if you only need to do this in a small section of your entire project, it wouldn't make sense to have to make all instances of `PQ` use virtual function calls. You could remedy this by having a wrapper class, lets say `wrap<T>` that inherits from the aforementioned `base` and it holds a `PQ<T>` internally. The wrapper class could then delegate the function calls to the internal structure. This way, you only pay for the virtual functions when needed, and not throughout your entire project.

Additionally, since your mixing types here, I'm assuming you're also going to mix types later on in your project, for which I  would recommend using `boost::any`.

Comment: @maor Since its an array of pointers, you need to say `arr[0] = &first;` or heap allocate them and store an array of `unique_ptr<base>` if duration is an issue.

Comment: I am trying to solve this without the use of std for my own learning.
the & did sort it out but now I get this error :" 1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual __thiscall Pointer_Base::~Pointer_Base(void)" (??1Pointer_Base@@UAE@XZ) referenced in function __unwindfunclet$??0?$PQ@H@@QAE@XZ$0
1>C:\Users\Navon\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\maorproject3\Debug\maorproject3.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals"

which I don't even know what is missing

Comment: Ok, but I don't see how productive that could be in the long run for your own benefit. You could manage your own memory (and lose the "std-ness" ) and still use this approach. Just use `new`/`delete` as opposed to smart pointers

Comment: @maor , you need to define a virtual destructor in your base class. What you did was `virtual ~Pointer_Base();`. What you need is `virtual ~Pointer_Base() {}`

Comment: ahh can believe all I missed was {} in the Ctor and Dtor. thanks.
BTW If I define in a base class a function and then write a function with the same name in the son's class , wouldn't it run over the base one?

Comment: @maor, it must be the same ***signature*** which includes const qualifiers and parameters. Without the `virtual`, you get good ol' overriding. If you have the `virtual` you get  polymorphic behavior

Comment: so in order to print the same way for int and string I need to write in the base class      `virtual void showall()=0;`    .[if anyone else in the future will see it it works].
again thanks for the help man.